# Problem in installing Kaolin v0.14.0 with cuda118 and torch_2.0.1 - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kaolin==0.14.0

Tags: pip, nvidia

When I use `pip install kaolin==0.14.0 -f https://nvidia-kaolin.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/torch-2.0.1_cu118.html`, to install Kaolin I get the following error:

```
Looking in links: https://nvidia-kaolin.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/torch-2.0.1_cu118.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kaolin==0.14.0 (from versions: 0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kaolin==0.14.0
```

When I tried to replace kaolin==0.14.0 with kaolin, it gets installed but with version 0.1.
Further with this version, when I try to import kaolin, it shows the following error:

```
    raise ImportError("This is the kaolin placeholder wheel from https://pypi.org/project/kaolin/. Please follow https://kaolin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html for installation.")
ImportError: This is the kaolin placeholder wheel from https://pypi.org/project/kaolin/. Please follow https://kaolin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html for installation.
```

Can someone help me install the version 0.14.0 or help mitigate the above error.